# Youtube webview stop next video

Tags: ios, video, youtube, uiwebview

I load an HTML article into `UIWebView` which contain video. However, after I finish playing the video, and I replay it, that video becoming the next video (maybe it's something like playlist, I don't know). How to stop it play next video when U replay that video? I just wanna play one video, do not next video.

I use default player iOS

I use this in webview (from API) :

```
<iframe src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/sample\" width=\"100%\" height=\"auto\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen=\"allowfullscreen\"></iframe>
```

Comment: Did adding autoplay=0 help?

Comment: I did. but it's not working

Comment: Finally, I found the SOLUTION. use '?rel=0' at the end of embed youtube id to disappear the video suggestion, so there's nothing suggest and next video

Sample :
from :
https://www.youtube.com/embed/TSUxbWmdNms
to :
https://www.youtube.com/embed/TSUxbWmdNms?rel=0

Thank to everybody for helping and answer :)
Best Regards

Comment: hello @SeishinOkigaru it is not working in iframe so please have any solution please share with me thanks.

Comment: Hello @ilesh , I used iframe and it's work in iOS webView. Do you use embed url in youtube?
Regards

Comment: Thanks  for your rpl , I trying  to set a flag '?rel=0, showinfo=0' and its working for me ..

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the "autoplay=0" parameter to the video source

```
src="//www.youtube.com/embed/AgwAywJlo1M?list=foo&autoplay=0"
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. it's still :)